# wordpress on xampp database error

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, apache

Hi I am trying to install worpress on xampp to design and test my blog on but when I go to localhost/wordpress it keeps telling me that

> "Error establishing a database connection"

Please help been trying everything.

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

I am running it on `Windows` `XP`

Comment: And your DB server is running under localhost and the passwordless user root is set up? Did you create the database 'wordpress'?

Comment: I have phpMyadmin pulled up, I did create a database wordpress everything is set to no password "as far as i know".

Comment: as far as you know? If you've got an user root without password you'll see a big red warning on the phpMyAdmin front page.

Comment: When I go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ it goes right to my phpmyadmin page with no warning

Comment: where would I go to get/change password? it says this at the bottom "Your configuration file contains settings (root with no password) that correspond to the default MySQL privileged account. Your MySQL server is running with this default, is open to intrusion, and you really should fix this security hole by setting a password for user 'root'."

Comment: The top menu says 'Users'. There you should find anything you need: Create new users, change passwords, ... If you're seeing the warning this means that your wordpress installation is set up correctly though. Do you see the database 'wordpress' in the list on the left side?

Comment: I deleted the database and made it over again. It is in the left panel yes. when I go to user tab password to everything is set to "no". There is 2 root icons one is localhost and other is linux. I am on Windows XP would that be a problem. Auto did that I didnt set for linux.

Comment: Does [this](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-error-establishing-a-database-connection-in-wordpress/) help you?

Comment: sure did thanks for your help been trying to get this going for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Try create Wordpress database on your MySQL server

Answer (score -1):

The error message would suggest that the details you have in your code sample are incorrect.

Do you have a 'wordpress' table?

Can you log into phpMyAdmin using the XAMPP suite using the account 'root' without a password?

You may need to setup a new user account with a password and grant the relevant privileges and then re-install Wordpress.

Comment: no I do not have a table set I am new to this and was not sure what that was. I have been to many sites and wat lots of videos and most all show to do the same thing. But when I try it i get the database error